# Is there any pair of positive integers $ (x,n)$ for which :$e^{{e}^{{e}^{\cdots x}}}=2^{n}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

I have tried to find a positive integer $x$ such that
$e^{{e}^{{e}^{x}}}=2^{n}$, for $n=2335$. I have got $x$ close to $2$ as shown [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5Ee%5Ee%5Ex%3D2%5E2335), then my question in general is :

> > **Question:** Is there any paire of positive integers $ (x,n)$ for which
> >     $$e^{{e}^{{e}^{\cdots x}}}=2^{n}?$$

Comment: Two questions: 1) In your very first equation, did you mean to use an $x$, $e^{e^{e^x}} = 2^n$? 2) What does the "$\cdots x$" mean?

Comment: x is the solution of the given equation, i want to know if it is possible that x, could be an integer , and n given

Comment: Are you trying to find two distinct integers $x$ and $n$ such that $e^{e^{e^x}} = 2^n$, or are you trying to find one integer $n$ such that $e^{e^{e^n}} = 2^n$?

Comment: I try to find a pair (x,n)  where x is integer , and it is good if i find a pair(n,n) in the case of x=n (special case)

Comment: @JohnBarber I take the "$\dots$" to mean $f_0(x)=x, f_{k+1}(x)=e^{f_k(x)}$ and then asking are there integers $x,k,n$ with $k,n\geq 0$ so that $f_k(x)=2^{n}.$

Comment: So this question is equivalent to: "Are there nested natural logs of some power of 2 which are integers?"

Comment: I doubt strongly that such triplets of integers exist, although I suppose you can get arbitrarily close. For instance, with trial and error, I find that $k=3$, $n = 762,451,794$ yields $x = 2.9999999999847836555$.

Comment: if it is then :$$e^{{e}^{{e}^{\cdots x}}}-1 $$ could be prime